# Component being added to the page, instead of the page being rerendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `question.js` component:

```
render() {
    return (
        this.state.questions.map((question) => {
            return (
                <section key={question.id} className='display-question'>
                    <div className='wrapper'>
                        <h3>Kategoria: {question.category}</h3>
                        <p>Poziom: {question.level}</p>
                        <p>Punkty: {question.pointAmount + question.pointBoost}</p>
                        <img alt='' style={{width: '80%'}} src={question.photoURL}/>
                    </div>
                </section>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

My `questions.js` component - it is a list, where the user picks the question he wants to see more of.

```
render() {
    return (
        <section className='display-question'>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
                    {
                        this.state.questions.map((question) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={question.id}>
                                    <h3>Kategoria: {question.category}</h3>
                                    <p>Poziom: {question.level}</p>
                                    <p>Punkty: {question.pointAmount + question.pointBoost}</p>
                                    <img alt='' style={{width: '20%'}} src={question.photoURL}/>
                                    <Router>
                                        <React.Fragment>
                                            <Link to={`/question/${question.id}`}
                                                  style={{display: 'block', margin: 'auto'}}>Rozwiaz to zadanie
                                            </Link>
                                            <Route exact path='/question/:id' component={Question}/>
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                    </Router>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

What I want: I want the component to be rendered as a separate page. Right now, the component is being appended to the bottom of the link. Like this:

[image]

So how can I make the `Question` component to be rendered on it's own? Not to be appended, but to be the only component there.

My navbar navigation does it the way I want, but I cannot see how it's different from the links way of doing things:

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Router>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Bar>
                        <Bar.Header>
                            <Bar.Brand>
                                <Link id='home' to="/">UczIchApp</Link>
                            </Bar.Brand>
                        </Bar.Header>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer id='about' to='/about'>
                                <NavItem>O nas</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            {
                                this.state.user ?
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <LinkContainer id="questions" to='/questions'>
                                            <NavItem>Zadania</NavItem>
                                        </LinkContainer>
                                        <NavItem onClick={this.logout}>Wyloguj się</NavItem>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                    :
                                    <NavItem onClick={this.openLogin}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
                            }
                        </Nav>
                    </Bar>
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <Route exact path="/questions" component={Questions}/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                </React.Fragment>
            </Router>
            <Modal
                show={this.state.show}
                onHide={this.handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header
                    closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title> Modal
                        heading </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <form>
                        <FormControl
                            id="email"
                            type="email"
                            label="Email address"
                            placeholder="Enter email"/>
                        <FormControl id="password" label="Password" type="password"/>
                        <Button onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj</Button>
                    </form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button id="close" onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had multiple `Routers` declared. Link to a post that solved it: [React router renders component after a refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696572/react-router-renders-component-after-a-refresh)